# Why is Aero Snap not working and how do I turn it on?

Tags: windows-7, aero

I'm currently using my [girlfriend's laptop](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Nav?h_pagetype=s-001&h_lang=en&h_cc=id&h_product=1849899&h_client=s-s-r2515-1&lang=en&cc=id) with Windows 7 Ultimate but [Aero Snap](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/snap.aspx) isn't working.

[image]

**Why is Aero Snap not working and how do I turn it on**?

Comment: This link might help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-problems-with-Windows-Aero

Comment: Side note: Aero snap is unrelated to Aero and should work independent of the selected theme.

Comment: Good point @Johannes: I thought it was related to the theme, but I tested it and you can have the Windows 98 theme with Aero Snap :-P

Comment: I know. I'm RDP-ing frequently into a Windows 7 and a Server 2k8 machine, both for bandwidth reasons with the classic theme. And it still works :)

Comment: Guess it's not as hardware intensive as the name makes it seem either... I was hoping for a whole slew of things you should check to find the cause :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the accessibility options (Win+U) under *»Make the mouse easier to use«* is a setting *»Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen«*. Is that turned on, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

I discovered a much easier way on enabling / disabling the snap function:

Go to Control Panel > Ease of Access Centre

Select ' Make the mouse easier to use'   ( I know its nothing to do with the mouse)
At the bottom under 'Make it easier to use windows' mine had a checkbox with a tick in under '**Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen**'

It now works again, I'd never seen this page before but yet the checkbox was checked, I can only put it down to a corrupt file

Comment: Thank you very much! Gosh.. Why did Windows shut this down randomly? I got use to this function and it went off one day.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Windows key + U". look under "Making the mouse easier to use". Like it has already been stated, make sure that it is not checked; however, I found that mine was not checked, but understanding how windows can be I "checked and applied it then disabled it". This fixed it, go figure :)