# Windows 8.1 Restoring Lost Windows+Right/Left,etc. Hotkeys

Tags: windows, keyboard, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hotkeys

Does anyone know how to restore the lost hotkeys that were removed in Windows 8.1.  Starting in Windows 7, there were some really handy hotkeys like Win+Right to dock the currently active window to the right half of the monitor, and then Win+Left with undock it back to its original position, or dock it to the left half of the monitor.

These all started in Windows 7, including Shift+Win+Left to move the window to the next monitor to the left, and even worked in Windows 8, but seem to have disappeared in 8.1.  I've been googling for the last hour without success ;(

Anybody know some magic to fix this?  I know I can re-create them with AutoHotkey (which I use obsessively all the time), but I don't want to be bothered if I don't have to.

Thanks,

Comment: I can't help you with this, because they work on my windows 8.1, so they were not removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Aero Snap not working and how do I turn it on?](http://superuser.com/questions/127153/why-is-aero-snap-not-working-and-how-do-i-turn-it-on)

Comment: Not really - they're similar features but independant.