# Can't resize windows with dragging their top

Tags: windows-10

Recently this problem occured. I don't know why, but now I can't just drag windows to top, left or right part of the screen to resize the, quickly. I kind of got used to this, so now it is just frustration that nothing happens when I try to do that.

It is not a tablet mode as many people in internet suffer from, and I couldn't find any clue to deal with this..

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1039039/how-to-disable-aero-snap-without-disabling-winr-winl-on-windows-10/1041137#1041137
or maybe:

https://superuser.com/questions/127153/why-is-aero-snap-not-working-and-how-do-i-turn-it-on

Comment: @Stephen Rauch thank you very much! This one actually helped: https://superuser.com/questions/127153/why-is-aero-snap-not-working-and-how-do-i-turn-it-on

Comment: @Stephen Rauch should I delete this topic or do something by the rules?

Comment: Delete away, there are no answers yet....

Comment: And there are no hard rules....

Comment: @Stephen Rauch I mean the only reason to leave it is that I couldn't find my answer myself, so this one kind of redirect people to it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why it is your choice.  I flagged it as duplicate, but that is not a problem,